# IIf clause in Access doesn't work correctly

Tags: ms-access, iif-function

I'm trying to create a table for invoice in Access and this is my table schema:

```
id AutoNumber
customer_name Number
product_name Number
count Number
unit Calculated
date Number
```

The customer name and product name are lookup wizard that select their data from another table.
I need the unit automatically select the unit based on product name for example:

```
"ورق آ۴"
```

for these unit must fill itself with:

```
"برگ"
```

and for these:

```
"مداد"
```

must fill itself with:

```
"عدد"
```

so I write an expression for this:

```
IIf([product_name]="برگ","ورق آ۴",IIf([product_name]="عدد","مداد","-"))
```

but it fills all of the product units with "-".
Any solution?

Comment: If product_name is a number, why are you comparing to string?

Comment: its not a number its lookup wizard and fills with short text data type but automatically after setting up the look up wizard it set the product_name with number data type

Comment: and also it works correctly ! @june7

Comment: It works correctly? Then what is the issue? customer_name and product_name are number fields so Lookup saves a number even though it displays descriptive text.

Comment: Advise not to set lookups in table. Design combobox on form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try so many solutions but at last I decided to use product_id and work with it it's so simple and Access doesn't need to encode the text in IIf and compare any more!

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely the encoding issue.
You can try:

- open an editor that can handle encoding - like Notepad++
- set a new empty file with Unicode ( or UCS-2 )
- paste your product name
- convert to UTF-8
- copy and paste to your Access formula.

Worked for me with your product_name(s)

brgds,
m.